# How do I compute the angles of a pyramid from the angle between its sides?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, 3d

I have been given the following problem to solve:

In a right pyramid whose base is an equilateral triangle, the angle between 2 side-faces is 70 degrees. Compute the base angle of a side-face.

I have little idea how to tackle this problem. I understand the definitions, but don't feel like any of my attempts is even worth mentioning in this arena.

Comment: Questions get more attention if 1) they are not presented as commands, and 2) there is some indication that the person presenting has actually tried to work on the problem, understands the definitions, tells us where the problem comes from, etc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I'm not sure how to best phrase it then.. If you can edit the question so that I learn what is expected it would be great. This is a high-school problem in 3D trigonometry, and I have little idea how to tackle it. I understand the definitions, but don't feel like any of my attempts is even worth mentioning..

Comment: Your attempts *are* worth mentioning, if only because it will encourage more people to help you.

Comment: hint: Use the information to try to find the normal vectors of the side facets. The direction of those normals will depend upon the height of the pyramid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer a purely trigonometric approach:

Let the equilateral triangle be ABC with centre O and side $2$ units. The vertex of the pyramid is V.

Let N be the foot of the perpendicular from A to line VB, so that $\angle ANC=70$ as given and the triangle ACN is isosceles.

Then $$AN=\frac{1}{\sin 35}\Rightarrow\angle ABN=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2\sin 35}\right)$$

Let X be the foot of the perpendicular from V to the line AB.
Then $$VX=1\times \tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2\sin 35}\right)\right)$$

Finally, the angle we are looking for is $\angle VXO=\theta$, where $$\cos\theta=\frac{OX}{VX}$$.

Now $$OX=\frac 13 CX=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Hence the required angle is given by $$\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2\sin 35}\right)\right)}$$

So $$\theta=71.06$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanx! I haven't thought about assuming the length of the sides of the base of the pyramid, although now that I think of it it was pretty stupid of me because obviously that length doesn't matter..

Answer (score 2):

The absolute size of the pyramid is irrelevant. Therefore we may assume that the vertices of the base triangle are
$${\bf a}_0=(1,0,0),\quad{\bf a}_1=\left(-{1\over2},{\sqrt{3}\over2}\right),\quad {\bf a}_2=\left(-{1\over2},-{\sqrt{3}\over2}\right)\ ,$$
and the top vertex is at ${\bf s}=(0,0,h)$ with an unknown $h>0$. The outward normal of the triangle $T_2:=[{\bf a}_0,{\bf a}_1,{\bf s}]$ is given by
$${\bf n}_2=({\bf a}_0-{\bf s})\times({\bf a}_1-{\bf s})\ ,$$
and similarly the outward normal  of the triangle $T_1:=[{\bf a}_0,{\bf a}_2,{\bf s}]$ is given by 
$${\bf n}_1=({\bf a}_2-{\bf s})\times({\bf a}_0-{\bf s})\ .$$

Now fix $h$ in such a way that $\angle({\bf n}_1,{\bf n}_2)=110^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

If the vertex of the pyramid is at the center of a unit sphere, then the sides of the pyramid would intersect the sphere in an equilateral triangle with angles of $\newcommand{\degree}{{\unicode{x00B0}}}70\degree$. The [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) says
$$
\cos(A)=-\cos(B)\cos(C)+\sin(B)\sin(C)\cos(\alpha)\tag{1}
$$
Plugging in $A=B=C=70\degree$, we get the cosine of each side of the spherical triangle to be
$$
\cos(\alpha)=\frac{\cos(70\degree)+\cos^2(70\degree)}{\sin^2(70\degree)}=\frac{\cos(70\degree)}{1-\cos(70\degree)}\tag{2}
$$
Thus, the area of each side of the pyramid is $\frac12\sin(\alpha)$. The area of the base of the pyramid is $\frac{\sqrt3}4s^2=\sqrt3\sin^2\left(\frac12\alpha\right)$. The cosine of the angle between the base and sides is the ratio of the area of the base over the sum of the areas of the sides
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(\theta)
&=\frac{\sqrt3\sin^2\left(\frac12\alpha\right)}{\frac32\sin(\alpha)}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\left(\tfrac12\alpha\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives
$$
\theta=71.06288\degree\tag{4}
$$